# Get data from Serialport using Callback?

Tags: matlab, callback

I am using this function:

https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/use-events-and-callbacks-for-serial-port-communication.html

```
        function readSerialData(s,~)
            data = readline(s);
            disp(data);
        end
```

```
configureCallback(s,"terminator",@readSerialData)
```

To get data from my connected device. The device receives new data every second or so (50 Bytes), so I get the data displayed on the command line in real time. But I want to actually use this data, but I am not sure how to gather the variables.

I can not see any "data" variable in the workspace, to store it and plot a real time graph (that´s the target)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: The scope of the variable `data` is limited to the function `readSerialData` only. You have then to modify your function to either do something with the data already inside the function itself (f.e. plot it), or save it for example in a global variable.

Comment: It was actually that easy, thank you very much!